# How do I sort List of type FileInfo in c#/Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I have below code where in I'm converting pdf to Textures ion unity, then I will be loading those textures into an array. But the pages are updated in array in unsorted format. How do I sort the array or List? Below is my code.

```
 public void GetPDFPages()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\TestBookPages\\");


        List<FileInfo> info = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg")
                             .Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file.Name, "^[0-9]+")).ToList();

        Debug.Log(info.ToString());
       

        tmpTexture = new Texture2D[info.Count];

        int y = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo f in info)
        {
            tmpTexture[y] = LoadImageFromFile(f.Directory + "\\" + f.Name);
            bool front = (y & 1) == 0 ? true : false;
            book.SetPageTexture(tmpTexture[y], y / 2, front);

            y++;
        }

       
    }

    public static Texture2D LoadImageFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        Texture2D tex = null;
        byte[] fileData;

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            tex = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
            tex.LoadImage(fileData);
        }
        return tex;
    }
```

Comment: Define sorted. By Filename? Then add something like `OrderBy(Name)` to your query that fills info.

Comment: Yes @Ralf by file name only

Comment: Then as said its `dir.GetFiles("*.jpg").Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file.Name, "^[0-9]+")).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();`
`

Comment: If you have an array then Array.Sort(array, (a, b)=> a.ValueToCompare.CompareTo(b.ValueToCompare)); if list then theList.Sort((a, b)=> a.ValueToCompare.CompareTo(b.ValueToCompare));